# When is it appropriate to report the results of a within-subjects contrasts table of a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, reporting

I've just run a repeated measures ANOVA in SPSS, with one 3-level within-subjects variable, and one 3-level between-subjects variable.

Is it correct to assume that one should be reporting the main within-subjects effect from the "tests of within subjects effects" table, and not the "tests of within subjects **contrasts**" table?

When would one report from the contrasts table, if not?

I'm asking because I am reviewing someone else's paper/data, and they have reported the repeated measures main effect from the contrasts table.

Comment: Can you show us your spss output? (Include it with editing the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SPSS RM-ANOVA output, the "Tests of within-subject effects" part of the output gives you the omnibus test for the within subject factor (e.g. if the within-subject is time 1,2, and 3, it tells you whether any of the times differs from any other) and, if there's also between-subject factor, this part of the output also gives you the omnibus test for the within-between interaction. It's typical (but not always strictly necessary) to report values from this part of the output by default.

Within-subject contrasts gives you, as default, linear and quadratic contrasts for the within factor. You would typically report either or both if you had a hypothesis about the within-subject factor having a linear and/or quadratic effect on the dependent variable. For instance, if you had given your participants medicine in 5mg, 10mg, and 15mg doses, you could have a linear hypothesis that the dependent variable changes linearly as a function of the magnitude of the dose. In this case, you would report the linear contrast. Of if you tested memory performance after 5min, 10min and 15 min, you could have a linear hypothesis about memory fading linearly as a function of time.

However, if your within-person factor represented three discrete conditions with no "order" (e.g. mood manipulations designed to make participants happy, angry and neutral), you would ignore the Within-Subject contrasts and probably look at pairwise comparisons between all manipulation pairs, or some custom contrasts. In SPSS these comparisons would be extracted from EM Means, not from Within-Subject contrasts.